# Bean definition is abstract Error on a Standalone Java application

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, jdbc

Im trying to create a ParentDao that will handle all the connection details for my Standalone Java application.
When I run my program I get the Error below

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanIsAbstractException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'parentDao': Bean definition is abstract

What am I doing wrong?
I know its an abstract class I was just following this examples which also used abstract classes. [abstract ParentDao Class](http://nikojava.wordpress.com/2009/08/29/easy-jdbc-using-spring/#spring-jdbc-design-en) and this one [DRY your Spring Bean](http://java.dzone.com/articles/dry-your-spring-beans) Im totally lost specially on how to do it on a Standalone application.  And where do I initialize the ApplicationContext and how.

Below is my Connection Properties (bean.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="dataSource" destroy-method="close"
        class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@ipaddress:1521:habagat" />
        <property name="username" value="username" />
        <property name="password" value="password" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="parentDao" class="com.mercury.dao.ParentDAO" abstract="true">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="childDao" class="com.mercury.dao.ChildDAOImpl" parent="parentDao"/>        
</beans>
```

BELOW IS MY MAIN METHOD

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
        "beans.xml");
ParentDAO parentDao = (ParentDAO) context.getBean("parentDao");
}
```

AND MY PARENT DAO CLASS

```
   public abstract class ParentDAO<T> extends JdbcDaoSupport {

        public abstract void insert(T object) throws Exception;

        public abstract void delete(int id) throws Exception;

        public abstract void update(T object) throws Exception;

        public abstract T select(int id) throws Exception;
}
```

MY SERVICE

```
public class myService {

    ChildDAO childDao;

    public String getChildrenCount() {


        return int totalCount = childDao.getRecordCount();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the Parent DAO *is* abstract. Why would you try to pull that bean out of the context? You want to get the childDao bean.

Comment: I was thinking that if I pass the context to the abstractDao all the child will have an available datasource <bean id="childDao" class="com.mercury.ChildDAO" parent="parentDAO" >

Comment: Put it this way: you're asking the bean factory to instantiate an abstract class, in effect.

Comment: could you guide me based from my given codes on how to configure this?  I could easily set abstract="false" but what else to configure for this to work? I would like the ParentDao to handle all the connection details

Comment: Instead of context.getBean("parentDao") do context.getBean("childDao")